# Embedding awk in a shell script

Tags: bash, awk

I've been using a bash script (script.sh) which uses various awk scripts (script1.awk,script2.awk) which are tailored at "runtime", by replacing values for instance.
I've been looking for ways to embed them completely within the first bash script.
Ideally, I would like to have a file looking like this :

```
################################
# AWK scripts                  #
################################
read -d '' scriptVariable <<'EOF'
'
{my block commands;}
'
EOF
################################
# End of AWK Scripts           #
################################
awk $scriptVariable ${inputfile} # This line obviously doesn't work
```

instead of the traditional :

```
awk '{
my script commands
' ${intputfile}
```

Of course, I could write them to a file but the whole point is not to. Any suggestions ?

EDIT : Although dogbane answers works fine, the next problem is that with the <<'HERE' tags, newline characters are not read.I can't unquote it since, otherwise, he's trying to interpret the awk script then encountering a $ sign within (and there are). And with no newlines, I can't comment anything within the awk script (without commenting half the script when the newlines characters are being removed ...). Anyone ?

```
<< 'EOF'
BEGIN{#Hello
print $1
}
EOF # Is read as BEGIN{#Hello print $1} by awk; ie BEGIN{

<< EOF
BEGIN{#Hello
print $1
}
EOF #Is read correctly by awk but Bash tried to express $1 and fails
```

Comment: Does it work with `awk "$scriptVariable" ${inputfile} `

Comment: It sounds like you simply need to upgrade your scripting language to something better - Perl or Python. It will be easier and work faster.

Comment: Already tried, it failed with `awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>> ' <<< 
awk: bailing out at source line 18`

Comment: why are you reading the variable when you can just set it with `scriptVar='...'` or better yet skip the whole setting of a variable and just use `awk ' ... ' file` ?

Comment: @technosaurus 1.Because there are nasty characters (',",..) in my string 2.Because I want to segregate the bash code and the awk code.

Comment: @Heisennberg that is what code folding editors/IDEs are for :)

Comment: @technosaurus As right as I agree you are, I would rather not having to do it in this case :D

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the awk script and enclose the script variable in double-quotes. This works for me:

```
################################
# AWK scripts                  #
################################
read -d '' scriptVariable << 'EOF'
BEGIN {
    print "start"
}
{
    print $0
}
END{
    print "hello"
}
EOF
################################
# End of AWK Scripts           #
################################

awk "$scriptVariable" ${inputfile}
```

Comment: To pass shell vars to the Awk script, use Awk's "-v" option.
Something like: 

**`var v1 = "shell value"
awk -v awkVar="$v1" "$scriptVariable" ${inputfile}
`**
In your script, 'awkVar' will hold the value "shell value"

Answer (score 2):

The single quotes around awk scripts can be cantankerous in a shell.

```
echo dummy code | awk '/dummy/{print '$1' $2}' - another_file | while read LINE; do
    case $LINE in
        "$1 code")echo success;;
        *)echo $LINE;;
    esac
done
```

This will remove from stdin and then another_file and output lines containing  dummy and replace the first field with the first argument to your bash script.  Notice that the bash variable $1 had to be unquoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can include your awk inside your bash script using a [Here-Document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells).

Comment: A tip on that, use the `-f - ` option, as in `awk -f - << EOD`

Comment: Why is the second - required?

Comment: Bruno's answer at https://superuser.com/questions/365452/how-to-write-awk-here-document worked for me.